# Dockerhub automated build fails, "not a directory" when adding file

Tags: dockerhub

I am trying to use docker hub to automatically build something that builds fine locally. It fails saying:

`Build process failed: stat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/1be9db483fa6f3de2596b5261e7c450de8df503185e579278396f14ba179c257/bin/run.sh: not a directory`

You can view the build itself here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/zbyte64/rethinkdb-tlsproxy/builds/bjclhq33kgwxxvn6nbfsgyh/

`run.sh` is in the same directory as `Dockerfile`, it seems the build path on dockerhub is different then where it stores the Dockerfile.

I have tried the following variations:

`COPY run.sh /bin`

`ADD ./run.sh /bin`

Comment: Also tried `ADD /run.sh /bin` with no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `COPY` command (on Dockerhub's Docker version) expects the target file on the right hand side, not just the target directory. The following command should work for you even on Dockerhub.

```
COPY run.sh /bin/run.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to use ADD, include the trailing slash.
`ADD ./run.sh /bin/`

What is actually happening? From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add :
ADD src dest
"If dest does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of src will be written at dest."

Without the trailing slash on /bin, it expects run.sh to be a directory being copied to directory /bin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but dockerhub wants the first argument of COPY or ADD to be a directory - not a file. I am running Docker 1.9.1 locally and that is not the case. I switched the Dockerfile to copy a resource directory instead of individual files and things started to work.